# Translate velocity from encoder count per second to meters per second

Tags: ros, velocity, encoders

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with a two wheeled robot, and I need the velocity of the wheels in meters per second, I have the encoder count per second, the wheel radius and the wheel distance. How can I translate this to meters per second?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67207/translate--velocity-from-encoder-count-per-second-to-meters-per-second/) by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-07-12**:
This really isn't a ROS question ... but, for a hint, you'll also need to know how many encoder counts per wheel revolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

wheel velocity = wheel rotation(rad/s) * wheel radius(m)

---

Originally posted by [redheli](https://answers.ros.org/users/3571/redheli/) with karma: 68 on 2013-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1